# Sub-menu open on currentpage and closed when other menu item is clicked

Tags: jquery, menu, submenu, current-page

I'm struggling with a horizontal menu with a sub-menu. I understand this is a frequent question and I've read the questions that are similar and tried many of the suggested solutions with little success. Of course some of the questions are specific or outdated.

I want the sub-menu to stay visible when a child page is open. Also I want one submenu to close when another is opened.

I found a jquery (1.7.2) which should help me with both problems. Even though it's one year old, I wanted to give it a try, because it looked so neat: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/slidetoggle-in-wordpress-menu-only-show-one-submenu-at-a-time

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j.fn.setNav = function () {
    $j('#nav ul li').css({
        display: 'none'
    });
    $j('ul#nav > li:has( ul li.current-menu-item )').each(function () {
        $j(this).find('ul.sub-menu').css({
            overflow: 'visible',
            height: 'auto',
            display: 'block'
        });
    });
    $j('ul#nav > li:has( ul.sub-menu )').click(function () {
        var $jsublist = jQuery(this).find('ul:first');
                $('.visible').slideUp('fast')
        $jsublist.slideToggle('fast').addClass('visible');
        return false;
    });
    $j('ul#nav > li > ul.sub-menu li ').click(function () {
        var subURL = $j(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
        location.href = subURL;
        return true;
    });
}
});
```

But it doesn't work. (I added

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

)

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CP8Er/17/

I would really appreciate help with this. I'm struggling with jquery and I hope your experienced eyes can see the problems that still aren't obvious to me.

Comment: You're not loading the jQuery library in your fiddle. To the left select the jQuery library you wish to use.

Comment: Oops, I've corrected that now. It's 1.7.2.